# Converting CAShapeLayer code from iOS to OSX

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I've code that draws an arc in iOS and have converted it for use in macOS.

Here's the iOS code that draws an arc.

```swift
    let circleCenter = CGPoint(x: self.frame.width / 2, y: self.frame.height / 2)
    let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: circleCenter, radius: self.frame.width / 2, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 1.5 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)

    let progress = CAShapeLayer()
    progress.path = circlePath.cgPath
    progress.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
    progress.strokeEnd = 0.4
    progress.lineCap = .round
    progress.lineWidth = 15
    progress.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
    self.layer.addSublayer(progress)
```

Here's the code that I've converted for use in macOS.

```swift
    let circle = NSBezierPath()
    circle.appendArc(withCenter: circleCenter, radius: self.frame.width / 2, startAngle: rad2deg(-CGFloat.pi / 2), endAngle: rad2deg(1.5 * CGFloat.pi))

    let progress = CAShapeLayer()
    progress.path = circle.cgPath
    progress.strokeColor = NSColor.green.cgColor
    progress.strokeEnd = 0.4
    progress.lineCap = .round
    progress.lineWidth = 15
    progress.fillColor = NSColor.clear.cgColor
    self.layer?.addSublayer(progress)
```

The code works in macOS, however, the resultant drawing is flipped. I understand that the starting coordinates are different in iOS vs macOS and that the macOS code should be altered to handle this. What is the best way to achieve this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: override var isFlipped: Bool { return true }

Comment: That worked. Thanks. Add as answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: That's not necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below answer from El Tomato worked.

override var isFlipped: Bool { return true }